# Why is my Firebase Realtime Database not opening on the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am building an android app, I remember i open the realtime database a day ago but really can't remember if I added any data before pausing the work for some rest. Now return the the firebase web console to view the database (if I did create any) or create a new one. Now the database tab doesn't show any data and if try to create one it shows that "An error occured, null" as in the screenshot image attached. Please any ideas on what to do?

[image]

Comment: 1) Check the developer console of your browser for any error messages. 2) try in an incognito window with all browser extensions disabled. If neither of those work, it might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. there are alot of messages on the dev console but the common error codes are 400 and 404 DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://console.firebase.google.com/u/2/project/.... HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: The same issue persists even in incgonito mode.